# React passing data between functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a beginner at React and I wanna go step by step using official tutorial: create Tic Tac Toe game. I have a hard time because I learn using functions, not Classes. When i try to implement it i get an error " Line 7:5:  'setSquares' is not defined". I think i need to pass some data from RenderSquare function to handleClick but i don't know how to do it..This is official example provided by React people:

[image]

My dumb code:

```
import Square from './Square';
import { useState } from 'react';

function handleClick(i) {
     const squares = squares.slice();
     squares[i] = 'X';
     setSquares({ squares });
}

 function RenderSquare(i) {
 const [squares, setSquares] = useState(Array(9).fill(null));

return (
    <>
        <Square
            value={squares[i]}
            onClick={() => {
                handleClick(i);
            }}
        />
        ;
    </>
   );
 }
```

Comment: you need to put the `handleClick` function inside the `RenderSquare` functional component. Currently, the `handleClick` function is outside of scope of `RenderSquare`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `handleClick` in the body of the component, so that `handleClick` will have scope of `setSquares`.

`setSquares({ squares });` should also be `setSquares(squares);`, since the state is an array, not an object.

```
function RenderSquare(i) {
    const [squares, setSquares] = useState(Array(9).fill(null));
    function handleClick(i) {
        const squares = squares.slice();
        squares[i] = 'X';
        setSquares(squares);
    }
    return (
        <>
            <Square
                value={squares[i]}
                onClick={() => {
                    handleClick(i);
                }}
            />
       ;
        </>
    );
}
```

I think the `const [squares, setSquares] = useState` line should also be in the *parent* component and passed down to the child - you don't want an array of squares *for every square rendered*, you want only a single array of squares.

```
const App = () => {
    const [squares, setSquares] = useState(Array(9).fill(null));
    return squares.map((val, i) => <Square {...{ i, squares, setSquares }} />);
};
function RenderSquare({ i, squares, setSquares }) {
    function handleClick() {
        const squares = squares.slice();
        squares[i] = 'X';
        setSquares(squares);
    }
    return (
        <>
            <Square
                value={squares[i]}
                onClick={() => {
                    handleClick(i);
                }}
            />
       ;
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But i have a question, if i would need to pass these data, like having 2 separate .js files, how would i do it?

Comment: Through the props, usually - like in the second snippet in the answer, I'm passing `i, squares, setSquares` as props from the parent to the child.